How can I silence the privacy alert (e.g. Screen Capture) for a specific app?
I use DisplayLink Manager to operate my dock and use external monitors. To do its job, it requires Screen Recording privilages. A blue icon in the menu bar indicates that "DisplayLink Manager is capturing your screen". I appreciate this alert, but because the alert is constantly visible, I ignore it and am now unaware if any other app is capturing my screen.
Is there a way to hide this alert for a single app? Even if this setting resets when I install a new version of the app, that's better than me becoming desensitised to these alerts.
I'm using MacOS Sequoia 15.2.


Is this the type of alert you want to disable?

Yes. Screenshot added.

I think you may be SOL on this one. I used to use DisplayLink Manager to connect an additional monitor.
However I had an issue that Amazon Prime Video wouldn't play whenever that monitor was plugged in (not that the Window was on that monitor, just that the monitor was plugged in). Because of this I strongly suspect that screen recording is more than just a "privacy" notification, I think its also used for DRM, as a result of that, I very much doubt you will be able to bypass it.
I finally gave up on DisplayLink Manager and just connected my additional monitor via HDMI - its annoying that I now have an additional wire to plug in, but everything works properly now.
